# Topic Discussion: an SO question closed

Tags: discussion

I found this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152704/function-that-returns-other-number-when-given-2-ints/35152812

on SO which was closed as being off-topic.

On 1st sight, it seems so but on giving a little thought to it, I think that it is not the case. The question may not show OP's attempts, but it is definitely not off-topic.

It looks like a logic question to me.

(Also, if I was the OP, I don't know how would I have shown my attempts to such a question. The function should just use input ints and return a different number than those two, without using conditionals. It is a single statement, which OP was unable to think of)

Comment: I don't care whether the close reason is correct or not. What counts is that it is closed, which it should be.

Comment: That is what I'm saying...the question should not have been closed. How should someone show you in writing the way he is thinking?

Comment: As I read it, it's trival.  It's also a no-effort homework dump or a troll.  Whatever, I wish I'd never seen it.

Comment: Can you give a solution to it, @MartinJames? Give a little thought and consider all cases.

Comment: @vish4071 no.  It's a 'drive a nail without using a hammer' question.

Comment: If it is not closed as off-topic it is too broad, and if it is not too broad it is unclear. We don't want questions that are just a requirement dump and then a bunch of users go write answers that are a fit for the OP (who probably has no clue how to use or interpret those answers) but are near useless for future visitors. No need to re-open that question.

Comment: If this is the case, most of the questions on SO should be closed as they are specific problems of the OP's. Most of the questions under `algorithm` tag are such questions which will be of no use to future visitors. @rene

Comment: Welcome in my world, I close a lot of those questions....

Comment: Outside of a classroom or programming competition, who would need such a question answered?  IMHO, using SO contributors as teaching staff and/or competition fodder is a misuse, if not actually abuse:(

Comment: @MartinJames, so you should not just say that it is a trivial question.

Comment: So you also think it is of use to students and participants of competition. @rene, there is your point contradicted by Martin.

Comment: @vish4071 OK, I meant trivial in the sense of 'trivial to deal with'. I will agree that an actual solution is not trivial and may not even be possible.  You cannot understand how little I care about such 'drive a screw with a toothpick and stick of dynamite' questions:(

Comment: I don't think Martin and I are much contradicting each other. We use different arguments to reach the same goal: the question stays closed.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "this is a non-trivial puzzle question (which may even be fun)" with "this question is on-topic". It is not.

Comment: Yeah right...I made a fuss over a poor question.

Comment: So where can such a question be asked? If the OP had added the answer which was posted by someone as his own try and say it fails, will the question be valid?

Comment: @Vini with an attempt and an explanation where and how it doesn't meet the requirement it would become on-topic, yes. If the OP can't do that they have plenty of other sites, often called forums, where they can give it a try.  Quora.com and reddit.com seem to be some high traffic sites that are open for stuff is not  on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does that mean that i can ask d same qn with al my tries?

Answer (score 6):

The question was correctly closed, although the custom close reason used wasn't really needed. It could have been closed as "unclear what you are asking", as it is unclear what part of the problem the poster is having problems with. We don't know if he has problems understanding the question itself, the algorithm needed or how to implement it in C. "Too broad" would be fine as well.

Furthermore, questions that seem like obvious homework fall under this rule from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Now as it happens, this applies to all questions, not just homework ones.

---

Off-topic:

For those who are so terribly interested in the actual problem that they can't dismiss it even though the question was poor, this code solves the problem:

```
int neither (int a, int b)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i==a || i==b; i++)
  {}

  return i;
}
```

Comment: Well, some might say that the question prohibits '==' comparisons and the implicit compare in for(z;y;z);, I could not possibly comment:)

Comment: `i == a || i == b` is just a sneaky way of writing `if`, it does not solve the problem. That's why it's much harder than it looks. My first knee-jerk reaction (just like almost everyone who saw in the original question and this one) was "homework, close", but actually thinking for a while about it the problem is much harder than it looks.

Comment: @Art It seems like it's off-topic for SO, but on-topic for meta:)

Comment: @all...This was the reason I put it here on meta. The question was poorly worded (no doubt), but it was an intriguing puzzle. I made a fuss over something which not deserved it. Lets end it :)

Comment: well, one could try on [codegolf.se], maybe.